# how to execute vba macro outside of excel

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with a massive amount of VBA and macros that include a button.

## How do I execute VBA code in Excel (specifically to clicking the button and trigger its onclick event) outside excel from python (for example)?

**Note**: I'm willing to take answers in different languages like C++, C#, or Java; but, by far I would prefer them in python since it'll more smoothly connect with the remainder of my python applications.

**Note 2**: I may need to manipulate the excel spreadsheet with python using one of the python excel libraries available

Version Numbers:

```
Microsoft Excel Office 365 Version 1708 Build 8431.2079
python 2.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon dylan's excellent answer: you can also accomplish the same using the python [`xlwings`](https://www.xlwings.org/) package. In essence `xlwings` is a fancy wrapper around `pywin32` that allows control of an excel application with even simpler syntax. The following python code should do the same as the code from dylan's answer:

```
import xlwings as xw

# Connect to existing workbook containing VBA macro
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\YourBookHere.xlsm')

# Run the VBA macro named 'MacroName'
wb.macro('MacroName')()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the win32com library to interact with COM Objects through Python. You can to install the win32com library with pip. That's how I did it at least. Essentially, you are not clicking the button on your worksheet, but instead calling the subroutine embedded in your VBA code to run on your worksheet.

Also, I used Python 3.6 for this, but I believe Python 2.7 should be compatible. Here is a basic outline.

**Install Win32Com**

Open up and command prompt and type:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

**Code**

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application") # create an instance of Excel
#excel.Visible = 1 #Uncomment this to show Excel working through the code
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'C:\YourBookHere.xlsm')
excel.Run("YourBookHere.xlsm!Sheet1.MacroName") # This runs the macro that is on Sheet1
book.Save()
book.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Hope this helps, this is my first post.
Edit: Cleaned up things a bit

Comment: Hey, you use "Sheet1" to locate the macro. Is there a way to specify the actual sheet name? I tried Worksheets("name"). No dice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also use Windows Task Scheduler to fire the event.  If a button-click-event fires the code, you can do exactly the same thing, by following the instructions in the link below.

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

Also, you will need a Workbook-open-event, so, something like this...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Msgbox "Welcome to ANALYSIS TABS"
End Sub
```