# Can I click VBA buttons in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

Aim: Copy data row-wise from one excel file to another.

Problem: I've used OpenPyXL earlier to automate such stuff, but have never dealt with a protected sheet earlier. This sheet requires the "validate" button to be pressed upon opening. Only when it has been validated, the "Add New Row" button works. Is there any way I can imitate clicking these buttons when copying data. Open to using different excel integration modules.

Note: A few columns in the sheet are "Auto Populating." This auto-population only works when I click the "Add New Row" button after filling in each row.

PS: I have access to the Protected VBA Code, but I have no experience with VBA. I can try running the macro that is supposed to be run when the button is clicked, but I don't know how to do that too.

[image: The "VBA Buttons"]

Comment: if you know which function is running on clicking the button, i believe you can run that function from python, you don't have to click the button.

Comment: This will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374578/how-to-execute-vba-macro-outside-of-excel

Comment: Hi. Did you get any solution for this? I have exactly the same problem. Having some protected Macros in VBA even hacking and copying those codes did not work. So I have to tell my Python code to click that button for me!